# How to sleep on puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
(async () => {
await page.evaluate(({List}) => {
        async function sleep() {
            getCurrentList(List[i]);
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            sleep();
        }

},{List});
}
```

Any idea why its returning this error bellow when calling this function?

Im trying to force the script pause 3 seconds after calling the function `getCurrentList`.

```
The FetchEvent for "https://" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
serviceworker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode
    at Object.manuallyCloneRequest (serviceworker.js:1)
    at g.fetchAndPut (serviceworker.js:1)
    at serviceworker.js:1
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be with `getCurrentList()` and not catching errors

Answer (score 0):

You can't call another function inside of `await page.evaluate`. You need to do your logic inside of this function, and return the serialized objects, and then call the sleep function, outside of the evaluate function scope.

For example:

```
(async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com/', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
 const articles = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.storylink')).map(el => el.textContent));
 console.log(articles)
 await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: cant understand what you mean, any example?

Comment: @Guto Added example.